# Wget - How do I download some files from ftp server?

Tags: ftp, wget

I am trying to download some files from a directory in ftp server. I would like to use "wget" command, but I can't get them.
ftp server URL: ftp://192.168.0.10
ftp user name: GL840
ftp password: no password
folder name in ftp: SD1/181004/

I am using the following command to download all files in the folder SD1/181004 in ftp server.
command is "wget -r -nd ftp://GL840:@192.168.0.10/SD1/181004/ -P /root/wang/powerdata/"

However, the following message is displayed and files are not downloaded.
Could you please tell me how to modify my command to download files?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have tried accessing file on ftp server. Usually I follow the following commands and this works for me. You can give a try with this command

wget --user='GL840' --password='' ftp://192.168.0.10/SD1/181004/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this command "wget -r -nd --ftp-user=GL840 --ftp-password=  ftp://192.168.0.10/SD1/181004/ -P /root/wang/powerdata/". The files are not downloaded.